# tail recursive/efficient function to count list items (without using List.count/Seq.count)

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I tried doing a tail recursive function that will count the elements of a list, followed the rules, used an acumulator, but when I run it like this:

```
lstcountr [1..98765432];;
```

I get this:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

this is my function (which I thought is tail recursive /efficient):

```
let lstcountr ls =
    let rec loop ls total = 
        match ls with
        | [] -> total
        | hd::tl -> loop tl total+1I
    loop ls 0I
```

can this be done better ?

Comment: A version using `seq<_>` could be something like: `let count = Seq.fold (fun i _ -> i + 1I) 0I`

Comment: @Daniel you should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: I used to really worry about recursive functions but having found that you can pretty much do the same thing with folds (as @Daniel points out above) I never worry about that stuff.  Folds are much easier to use and I believe tail recursion is pretty much built in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You function isn't tail recursive.

```
| hd::tl -> loop tl total+1I
```

Should be

```
| hd::tl -> loop tl (total+1I)
```

Operators are interpreted after function calls, normally you can't tell in situations like this because the results are identical, but that is not true with tail recursion.

Also as Tejs said, you are creating a list of too many items which is causing your `OutOfMemoryException`. Have you tried using a `seq { }`?

Comment: Good catch about the calculation of (total+1I).  Really a subtle point.

Answer (score 5):

Too much recursion would mean you get a `StackOverflowException`, not an `OutOfMemoryException` - This is because you're trying to create a list of 98765432 elements at once.

Regardless of your recursion, this list passed as the argument is created in memory, not lazily I might add.

Comment: ok, I tried doing this separately, and the list gets made (it does takes some time), and after when I try to count it I do get `StackOverflowException`, so it's still not working, I guess it's too much recursion anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways of writing a sequence-based version that's polymorphic in its return type:

```
module Seq =
  open LanguagePrimitives

  let inline count items = Seq.fold (fun i _ -> i + GenericOne) GenericZero items

  //faster
  let inline count (items: seq<_>) =
    use e = items.GetEnumerator()
    let rec loop n =
      if e.MoveNext() then loop (n + GenericOne)
      else n
    loop GenericZero
```

This allows you to compute length using the the most suitable type:

```
let n : bigint = Seq.count {1I .. 987298234982374923847I}
let n : float = Seq.count {1I .. 987298234982374923847I}
```